# Unable to install MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04 - mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to install mysql server and client on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04).
I am running following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

But I'm getting the following error when the machine installing mysql client

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 10.0.24+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me to install mysql

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Thank you for your response Nijraj. But It did not work for me

Comment: try this :      sudo apt-get update

Comment: I did it too but no luck

Comment: I got the following error when I ran  sudo apt-get update
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.almahost.co.uk/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `sudo apt-get install -f libmysqlclient18=5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` and it worked for me.

For different versions of the force install, I think you just need to explicitly show the version of the package that needs to be installed as a dependency. E.g.

> **From the error log:**
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: **libmysqlclient18** (= **5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1**) but 10.0.24+maria-1~trusty is to be installed

gets you to **libmysqlclient18=5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1** as the dependency.